# Android SetEnable has an obscured view

Tags: android

I use setEnabled on RadioGroups, EditText, Spinner, and Checkbox. However when I do so the data is very dark to see (have to squint at it). How do I make it so that the disabled controls can be viewed easily by the user AND have it differentiated from the editable mode controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to provide the drawables for the background of each control. You'd probably want to implement a selector to change the image based on the state.